# Underline blank rows area in handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, handlebars.js

Using HandlebarsJS

I have a blank area with with dynamic content rendered. When text is not reaching min-height the content must contain empty underlined blank rows.
I tried using a background image in css like follows:

```
.regimul-juridic {
    /*background-color: red;*/
    margin-top: -5px;
    min-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-position: fixed;
    line-height: 18px;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAASAQMAAACgmSb/AAAABlBMVEUAAAAAAASiCn3WAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAtJREFUCNdjIAwaAACkAIHWnJmDAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
    backdrop: static;
}
.regimul-juridic > p {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 9px;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

but without success, because if there is more content on the area above the image will not expand properly. Does anyone have a solution ?
Picture showing what I am trying to achieve here:
[image: blank rows]

Answer (score 1):

For the underline you can use hr tags in the html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the thing is that I must have that area with a min-height. I can't set how many hr's will fit in that min height.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I can't seem understand what you mean. If you need to set a min-height for all the hr's you can just write hr without hash or . and style in css, it will style all of them